# Create subdictionary from dictionary if values in dictionary are also in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
keys = [1., 2., 3., 4., 5.] 
values = [0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.0, .25]
dic = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

and would like to create a subdictionary that only includes the keys and values from the first dictionary if the values of the first dictionary are also in a list.

```
list = [ 1., 0.8, 0.8, 0.4, 0.0]
```

I want the subdictionary to be:

```
subdic = {1.:0.8, 2.:0.8, 4.:0.0}
```

I would appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: Don't call a variable `list`; you are masking the built-in type. In my answer below I assume it is called `lst` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dict-comprehension:

```
>>> dic = dict(zip(keys, values))
>>> lis = [ 1., 0.8, 0.8, 0.4, 0.0]
>>> {k:v for k,v in dic.items() if k in lis or v in lis}
{1.0: 0.8, 2.0: 0.8, 4.0: 0.0}
```

For Python 2.6 or earlier versions `use dict()` with a generator expression:

```
>>> dict((k,v) for k,v in dic.items() if k in lis or v in lis)
{1.0: 0.8, 2.0: 0.8, 4.0: 0.0}
```

In Python 2 you can use `dict.iteritems()` as it returns an iterator. `dict.items()` will work on both versions.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to build a dictionary based on a filter, use a dict comprehension:

```
subdic = {k: v for k, v in dic.iteritems() if k in lst or v in lst}
```